# how to convert special characters URL C #

Tags: c#, url, character

I have the following urls:

```
https://example.com/trabajo-abogado-civil/A-Coru%25C3%25B1a-guti%25C3%25A9rrez
```

and when I get the html code, it returns me:

```
Excepción producida: 'System.Net.WebException' en System.dll
```

I tried to code to ascii and also UTF-8 but it always returns the exception.

```
private string obtenerPaginaHtml(string urlPaginaHtml)
{           
    try
    {             
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlPaginaHtml);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {                 
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;

            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            }
            else
            {
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            }

            string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();

            //MessageBox.Show(data);
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }            
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {              
        ThreadController.InvokeIfRequired(log_listBox, () =>
        {
            log_listBox.Items.Add("Error 24 HTML: " + urlPaginaHtml + ": " + e.ToString());
        });
        logTXT("Error 24 en " + urlPaginaHtml + ": " + e.ToString());
        return "";       
    }
}
```

The final result would be this:

```
  https://example.com/trabajo-abogado-civil/A-Coruña-gutiérrez
```

Comment: Does the encoded url work in a browser?

Comment: Are you trying to unescape a percent-escaped string?

Comment: ``System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str);``

Comment: Are you looking for [`UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Your string is double encoded. Do `UrlDecode` on it twice.

Comment: The url does not work in the browser

Comment: You can try it if you want: https://www.paginasamarillas.es/a/abogado-empresa-sociedad/a-coru%25C3%25B1a/a-coru%25C3%25B1a/      The functional url would be the following: https://www.paginasamarillas.es/a/abogado-empresa-sociedad/a-coruña/a-coruña/

Comment: I do not know what the percentage-scaped is

Comment: I have used: System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode (url); and I think it works. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As @Crowcoder said, your address is double encoded, but even if you properly decode you will get a 404 error message.

I've made some tests with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = String.Empty;

        var urlPaginaHtml = "https://example.com/trabajo-abogado-civil/A-Coru%25C3%25B1a-guti%25C3%25A9rrez";
        urlPaginaHtml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(urlPaginaHtml));

        //urlPaginaHtml = "https://www.google.com.br/"; <-- WORKS

        Console.WriteLine("URL: " +urlPaginaHtml);

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlPaginaHtml);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                //var data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                result = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();

                //MessageBox.Show(data);
                //return data;
            }
            else
            {
                //return ""; 
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DONE!!!");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("#ERROR#: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Rr8YF